# acf_form() validation and feedback

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm creating a front-end form for submitting new post (I hope most of you are familiar with it) with the following code:

```
$options = array(
    'post_id' => 'new_post',
        'new_post' => array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'   => 'pending'
    ),
    'html_before_fields' => $html_before_fields,
    'html_after_fields' => $html_after_fields,
    'uploader' => 'basic',
    'submit_value' => __("Create", 'domain'),
    'updated_message' => __("Your post was submitted successfully! Please wait for it to be approved.", 'domain'),
);

acf_form($options);
```

And here is a snippet of my functions.php;

```
function _action_ssd_acf_submit_post_pre_save( $post_id ) {

    if( empty($_POST['acf']) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( !isset($_POST['acf_post_submit']) ) { // this is a hidden input field in the form
        return;
    }

    if (  ) { // some more checks here
        wp_mail(); //removed parameters for cleaner code, I send email to the admin
    }  

    if( empty(get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'this_user_can_submit', true)) ) {
        exit;
        return;
    } 


}

add_action( 'acf/pre_save_post', '_action_ssd_acf_submit_post_pre_save' );
```

How can I stop the post from saving as it is always saved as Draft?

Also, I can't seem to find a way to change the `update_message` when there is an error wth the submission. For example, if the user doesn't have the needed `user_meta`.

So, yeah, my problem is that I am unable to stop the submission of the post (in case of a validation error) and send a front end message feedback after the page has refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the post to be published, not to be set as draft, you need to use `'post_status' => 'publish'` instead of `'post_status' => 'post'`.

Comment: I had made a mistake with writing the code here. Post status `'post_status' => 'post'` is the one it should have been written above. My problem is that I am unable to stop the submission of the post (in case of a validation error) and send a front end message feedback after the page has refreshed.